# Bad formatting - LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am making a homework in LaTeX. I need to use the fractions. And here I have a problem.

First fraction is displayed fine, code:

```
\rho = \frac{m}{V}, \hfill (1)
```

Its looks like it should. The problem is with next fractions. All are displayed in one denominator.

This is badly displayed when its not equation, for example: `x=\frac{wq}{21}`.

Here is my code: https://www.sharelatex.com/read/ntwzrgmkzxpn

How to display fractions correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want make a formula larger in in-line math mode. For instance, if you want an in-line mathematical element to display as a equation-like element put `\displaystyle` before that element in a formula: `x=\displaystyle\frac{wq}{21}`.

Answer (score 0):

The package `amsmath`, that you are already using, supplies the command `\dfrac{}{}` that you can use instead of `\frac{}{}` as a contract form for `\displaystyle\frac{}{}` for example in inline math or in nested fractions.